# Cannot run rasa server and rasa actions simultaneously

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa

Basically I am able run only one server(action or shell) at a time. So how can I run custom actions

This the error I get when I try to run them.

```
OSError: [Errno 48] error while attempting to bind on address ('0.0.0.0', 5005): address already in use
```

Command used for rasa server :

```
rasa shell
```

Command used for rasa action :

```
rasa run actions
```

Answer (score 1):

This error will appear when you're using the same port for both servers. You need to specify a different port for the action server.

In your project's folder, look for `endpoint.yml`
and change the port of the action server to a different number (rather than the default of `5005`).

For example:

```
action_endpoint:
  url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"
```

I hope it's clear :)

Answer (score 0):

I would not advice you to run both simultaneously, although there is a solution for that.

try giving `rasa shell` on one CLI and on the other try giving a differen port number like for example `rasa run actions --port 5007`. This will change your port no for the **Action Server** to port 5007.

The *action_endpoint* is a webhook for `rasa_sdk`.